# ConstraintViolationException, should I expect it to be thrown then handle it? or should I prevent it from being thrown?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

When writing database code, I usually prevent a ConstraintViolationException to be thrown by checking the records before updating or inserting.

I do not wait for a ContraintViolationException's to take place then handle it. This is because a database administrator once told me that this is a bad practice.

But I'm seeing many developers handling the ContraintViolationException and Foreign Key exception, rather than manually checking for the violations using sql code.

**The question is? Which is better? Should I just handle such exceptions when they come up, or should I query the objects before insert/update operations and prevent these errors from being thrown?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better, meaning simplest way is handle such exceptions when they come up. Because that's the purpose of the try catch in the first place.

If you query the object before insert/update, your just adding up code that can slow down you application because database trips are resource intensive. Imagine if there are 1000 users and the application does that.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a wrong way, but keep in mind that doing a rollback in JPA will cause all managed entities for the current session to become detached.

Usually, a rollback is done after an exception is caught, and this can cause [bugs that are hard to track down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12675654/1073063). For this reason, I prefer to ckeck beforehand when working with JPA. I think that normally, we should not worry about efficiency at this point, that is usually premature optimization.